# How can I use a Quarto variable to include a code block?

Tags: python, yaml, markdown, quarto

I am trying to de-clutter a Quarto markdown document, using variables to include code blocks. I've created a `_variables.yml` file with

```
view:
    arvores: |
    {python}
    #| echo: false
    #| label: tbl-test
    #| tbl-cap: Volumes
    Markdown(tabulate(data,headers=data.columns,showindex=False))
```

with the following code in the `report.qmd` file:

```
{{< var view.arvores >}}
```

But the code is not executed. Is it possible to do this? Do I need to escape any character? Would it be easier to use Quarto **includes** instead of **variables**?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably possible to do this, but not with invalid YAML. YAML documents use indentations and the "body" of the value for the mapping key `arvores`, the block style literal scalar introduced by `|` is not indented. It should look like:

```yaml
view:
  arvores: |
    {python}
    #| echo: false
    #| label: tbl-test
    #| tbl-cap: Volumes
    Markdown(tabulate(data,headers=data.columns,showindex=False))
```